# Is it possible to import a KML to the map? - ArcGIS API 3.27

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to see if it is possible to upload a KML layer to display on the map. I have looked into using `KMLLayer`, but that requires a public URL to load in, and I can't use the file path of the file for security reasons (and because modern browsers change it to "c:\fakepath\file.kml" anyways for that very reason).

I tried to see if I can do client side conversion from KML to GeoJSON with `gtran-kml` and from GeoJSON to ArcGIS Geometry with `arcgis-to-geojson-utils`, but whenever I try to load the modules with `require` after installing them with `npm`, I keep on getting a module defined error in the console. I saw that it was trying to pull the module from the ArcGIS API. So I tried looking through the `require.config` file to see if it was set to the API, and it doesn't appear so. Using `./gtran-kml` instead of `gtran-kml` went to the root URL, but still gave the same error being thrown by ArcGIS's `init.js` file. I don't know if this is an issue with `npm`, with not installing in the correct directory, with not calling modules correctly (I used `var a = require('gtran-kml')` then `a.fnName` to use it), or all three.

I'm still relatively new to working with JavaScript. So if anymore information is needed, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `KMLLayer` class is really expecting that the KML file be sitting on an HTTP-accessible web server or file hosting service somewhere.

One fairly easy option is to log into ArcGIS Online, and create a hosted feature layer from the KML file. That gives you a REST endpoint, which you can then use as the url property of the `KMLLayer`.

For example: 
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=cf2f3a0f46c144dea3f88c8a4c3fe94c
https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/cf2f3a0f46c144dea3f88c8a4c3fe94c/data

Another option is to place the file on a web server somewhere, also making it HTTP-accessible.

For example:
https://jimbarry.github.io/junkdrawer/farmers_markets.kml

Beyond that, if you really need that file to stay on your local file system and appear as if it is an HTTP_accessible web resource, perhaps look into `FileReader`:

Here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Pretty sure how that would work is that `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` would then put a URL into the FileReader.result property. You'd then use that URL as the source for the `KMLLayer`. (that bit i'm not 100% sure on though)

For more info:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/layers_kml.html

Comment: I had looked into using `FileReader`. The problem was it would encode the data as a  giant URL string. So that string contained the actual data, and did not create a link to the file.

I figured the work around would be to upload it to a public file sharing service, but I wasn't sure if there was a way in the API to be able to upload the KML without having to do this.

Comment: Another option for keeping the .kml file on your local file system is to use a localhost web server. (Mac comes with Apache, Windows comes with IIS). So then, any files you want accessible to a locally running web app, just put it somewhere in the web server's root, and bobsyouruncle. If you want your end-user to be able to choose a file at runtime, use a file dialog, but either way, the file will need to be under the web server root, or in a virtual directory already setup with the web server.  But in the end, yes, the KMLLayer is expecting, at a minimum, that the file be HTTP-accessible.